# Kicad 6 missing symbols/footprints

Tags: kicad

Fresh install of Kicad on my linux machine. It has A LOT of footprints and symbols etc... but I cant find a simple polarized cap symbol or footprints for smd electrolytic capacitors..

They exist here: https://kicad.github.io/footprints/Capacitor_SMD

But that is supposedly for version 5 of kicad. I find it hard to believe they would make a V6 Kicad with less footprints. What is the missing piece here? Do I have to do some manual work to get all symbols after a fresh install?

Comment: Kicad's libraries are all on gitlab now, not github. I don't believe kicad version 6 was ever on github.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find several in the device library. Both European and US symbols are available.[image]

The footprints are available in the footprint library.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Capacitor symbols can be found in the Device library, located at `${KICAD6_SYMBOL_DIR}/Device.kicad_sym`

SMD capacitor footprints are in the Capacitor_SMD footprint library, at `${KICAD6_FOOTPRINT_DIR}/Capacitor_SMD.pretty`

You can add new symbol libraries by selecting `Tools -> Manage symbol libraries` and then selecting the folder icon:
[image: Symbol libraries window in KiCAD 6]

Adding a new footprints library is done similarly, by selecting `Manage footprint libraries` under `Preferences` when using the Assign Footprints tool.

When you create a new project, you'll get the option to link the default libraries. Did you choose any option other than the default?